How to filter for a specific value in an array property using Microsoft Graph API?
I'm running the MS Graph GET query below to find sign in events that have the 'extranet' value in the networkType property that is nested inside the networkLocationDetail property but I'm not getting any results even though there are plenty of events with that value. I get an "OK" response so I'm certain I'm constructing the query correctly.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditlogs/signIns$filter=networkLocationDetails/any(s:s/networktype eq 'intranet')

If I omit the filter using the query below I see all sign in events and see that there are plenty that have the value that I'm searching for in the 'networktype' property. I tried searching for all the different values that can exist in that property as listed in the same documentation (intranet, extranet, namedNetwork, trusted, unknownFutureValue) in the first link but I continue to not receive any results.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditlogs/signIns?


According to this other documentation I'm using the correct syntax when searching for a value in a collection of objects. Am I missing something here or is this type of filter not supported in the signIn resource ? I see several properties in the signIn resource that mentions the type of $filter that is supported (if any) but not for the one I'm searching for (networkLocationDetails). Does that mean it's not supported or am I missing something else here ? If it's not supported what are my other options ?
